# How do I set ad banner at top in landscape and at bottom in portrait?

Tags: android, admob, banner-ads

I want to show my AdMob banner on the bottom of the screen when the app is in portrait mode, and on top of the screen when it is in landscape mode. So how can I add these to my app?

Currently I'm using a separate layout (**layout-port** and **layout-land**)

Comment: send a request to show admob depended on the orientation , setup 2 different admobs (landscape and portrait) on the server and call each one accordingly?

Comment: Do you have two separate layouts and want the (xml-)code for that? Or do have a solution with two layouts and want (Java-)code instead?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to recognize the screen orientation. whenever screen changes it recreates the activity you can get screen orientation via fallowing method

```
int orientation=this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
if(orientation==Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
   //code for portrait mode
}
else{
    //code for landscape mode
}
```

try to add your layout programmatically. If you are using Relative layout you can use addRule like this

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, height);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, lastId);
```

You can add rules as per requirement. above is the way to add a rule. similarly there is a method to remove a rule

```
params.removeRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW);
```

Or if you want, can inflate a new layout in condition as per your need. 
*Hope this will help!*

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to do it.

#### XML-based ([recommended in many cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9827819/best-practices-layouts-on-android-programmatic-vs-xml), [also by @CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11960645/1587329)).

[Something like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151893/admob-banner-not-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen)

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    app:adSize="BANNER"
    app:adUnitId="a1512f50d8c3692"
    app:loadAdOnCreate="true"
    app:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID" >
</com.google.ads.AdView>
```

This should add it to the bottom via `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`. If you want it at the top, try [`android:layout_alignParentTop`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignParentTop) instead.

You will probably need to adjust this some (`adUnitId` comes to mind).
Then, in code, fill it with [something like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15155388/1587329)

```
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

#### Code-based

If you really want to do this the hard way, [@ashutiwari4's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34268886/1587329) looks good at first glance.